# Stanford NLP pipeline – sequential processing (in Java)

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

How to correctly use **Stanford NLP pipeline** for two-phase annotation?

---

In the **first phase** I need only **tokenization** and **sentence splitting**, so I use this code:

```
private Annotation annotatedDocument = null;
private StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = null;

...

public void firstPhase() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit");

        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        annotatedDocument = new Annotation(textDocument);
}
```

The **second phase** is optional, so I don't use all annotator in the first phase. The second phase code:

```
public void secondPhase() {
    POSTaggerAnnotator posTaggerAnot = new POSTaggerAnnotator();
    posAnot.annotate(annotatedDocument);

    // Lemmatization
    MorphaAnnotator morphaAnot = new MorphaAnnotator();
    morphaAnot.annotate(annotatedDocument);
}
```

---

**First question**: Is this approach using "stand-alone" annotators in the second phase correct? Or is there a way to use existing pipeline?

**Second question**: I have problem with Correference annotator. I would like use it in the second phase as follow:

```
CorefAnnotator coref = new CorefAnnotator(new Properties());
```

But this constructor seems to be never ending. Constructor without properties doesn't exist, right? Is it some properties setting necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [at least] 3 ways you can do this:

1. The way you described. It's perfectly valid to just call individual annotators, and chain them together. The coref annotator should work with empty properties -- perhaps you need more memory? It's a bit slow to load, and the models are not small.
2. If you want to keep using a pipeline, you can create a partial pipeline and set the property `enforceRequirements=false`. This will do the chaining of annotators for you, but doesn't require their requirements to be satisfied -- i.e., if you know some annotations are already there, you don't have to re-run their corresponding annotators.
3. This is a bigger change, but the [simple api](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html) actually does this sort of lazy evaluation automatically. So, you can just create a `Document` object, and when you request various annotations, it'll lazily fault them in.

Comment: You're right, problem with the **Coref annotator** is java.lang.OutOfMemmoryError exception.